# Reshaping data: long to wide; multiple variables, multiple values

Tags: r, reshape, tidyr

Hi and thanks for reading....

Here's a small sample of my dataset after edit:

```
data <- read.table(text=
"Site  Year   Day           Variable     Value Error  Unit
1  2004   238       Nitrogen-NO3 1.000e-03 2e-03  mg/L
1  2004   238       Nitrogen-NO2 2.500e-03 5e-03  mg/L
2  2004   238       Nitrogen-NO3 1.000e-03 2e-03  mg/L
2  2004   238       Nitrogen-NO2 2.500e-03 5e-03  mg/L
3  2004   238       Nitrogen-NO3 1.000e-03 2e-03  mg/L
3  2004   238       Nitrogen-NO2 2.500e-03 5e-03  mg/L
4  2004   238       Nitrogen-NO3 1.000e-03 2e-03  mg/L
4  2004   238       Nitrogen-NO2 2.500e-03 5e-03  mg/L
5  2004   238  General-SolidsTSS 6.430e-01 1e-04  mg/L
5  2004   238  Phosphorus-OrthoP 3.000e-03 1e-04  mg/L
5  2004   238      Phosphorus-TP 4.000e-03 1e-04  mg/L
5  2004   238        Nitrogen-TN 5.000e-02 1e-03  mg/L
5  2004   238       Nitrogen-NO3 1.000e-03 2e-03  mg/L
5  2004   238       Nitrogen-NO2 2.500e-03 5e-03  mg/L
5  2004   238 General-Alkalinity 6.500e+01 1e-02  mg/L
6  2004   237 General-Alkalinity 5.540e+01 1e-03  mg/L
6  2004   237  General-SolidsTSS 1.292e+01 1e-03  mg/L
6  2004   237       Nitrogen-NO2 2.000e-03 1e-03  mg/L
6  2004   237       Nitrogen-NO3 2.200e-02 1e-03  mg/L
6  2004   237       Nitrogen-TDN 9.000e-02 1e-03  mg/L
6  2004   237     Phosphorus-TDP 4.000e-03 1e-03  mg/L
7  2004   238 General-Alkalinity 4.430e+01 1e-03  mg/L
7  2004   238  General-SolidsTSS 2.340e+00 1e-03  mg/L
7  2004   238   Nitrogen-NO2+NO3 4.800e-02 1e-03  mg/L
7  2004   238       Nitrogen-TDN 2.700e-01 1e-03  mg/L
7  2004   238     Phosphorus-TDP 6.000e-03 1e-03  mg/L
8  2004   238       Nitrogen-NO3 1.000e-03 2e-03  mg/L
8  2004   238       Nitrogen-NO2 2.500e-03 5e-03  mg/L
9  2010   194                 Ca 1.450e+02 1e-01  mg/L
9  2010   194 General-Alkalinity 2.150e+02 5e-01  mg/L
9  2010   194   General-Hardness 4.800e+02 4e-01  mg/L
9  2010   194                SO4 2.540e+02 1e+01  mg/L
9  2010   194                 Bi 5.000e-07 1e-06  mg/L
9  2010   194                 Sn 2.500e-06 5e-06  mg/L
9  2010   194       Nitrogen-NO2 2.500e-03 5e-03  mg/L
9  2010   194       Nitrogen-NO3 2.500e-03 5e-03  mg/L
9  2010   194                 Br 1.000e-02 2e-02  mg/L
9  2010   194                  U 2.670e-03 5e-07  mg/L
9  2010   194                 Ag 3.000e-06 1e-06  mg/L
9  2010   194                 Be 1.300e-05 1e-06  mg/L
9  2010   194                 Cd 5.400e-05 1e-06  mg/L
9  2010   194                 Sb 8.500e-05 1e-06  mg/L
9  2010   194                 Tl 1.700e-05 1e-06  mg/L
9  2010   194                 Co 1.250e-03 2e-06  mg/L
9  2010   194                 Mo 1.510e-03 5e-06  mg/L
9  2010   194                 Pb 6.000e-05 5e-06  mg/L
9  2010   194                  V 3.860e-04 5e-06  mg/L
9  2010   194                 As 7.900e-04 1e-05  mg/L
9  2010   194                 Cr 1.600e-04 1e-05  mg/L
9  2010   194                 Li 3.230e-02 1e-05  mg/L", stringsAsFactors=F, header=T)
```

I need to format the data into WIDE format. I have meddled with recast, dcast, reshape, reshape2, cbind, combine..etc. I had the best of luck with recast but nowhere near a useful dataset.

From the dataframe above, I want to achieve something like this:

**see link to image*** here!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrO1U.jpg

Currently, data for 1 SITE is distributed amongst several rows. I would like all data for each SITE in one row (i.e. each site only appears once in the SITE column. Each unique VARIABLE should have a column, as well as corresponding columns of VALUE, ERROR, and UNIT, for each. i.e I think there's around 50 unique VARIABLES, so the new dataframe would have ~ 200 more columns.

I hope the explanation is sufficient; but don't hesitate to ask for clarification.

I suspect there's a simple answer out there from some of the more experienced users. Thanks in advance for the support. Cheers

Comment: Make a *small* reproducible example, and I'm sure it would be easy for others to help you out....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reshape the data as follows:

Load the data

```
data <- read.table(text=
"Site  Year   Day           Variable     Value Error  Unit
1  2004   238       Nitrogen-NO3 1.000e-03 2e-03  mg/L
1  2004   238       Nitrogen-NO2 2.500e-03 5e-03  mg/L
2  2004   238       Nitrogen-NO3 1.000e-03 2e-03  mg/L
2  2004   238       Nitrogen-NO2 2.500e-03 5e-03  mg/L
3  2004   238       Nitrogen-NO3 1.000e-03 2e-03  mg/L
3  2004   238       Nitrogen-NO2 2.500e-03 5e-03  mg/L
4  2004   238       Nitrogen-NO3 1.000e-03 2e-03  mg/L
4  2004   238       Nitrogen-NO2 2.500e-03 5e-03  mg/L
5  2004   238  General-SolidsTSS 6.430e-01 1e-04  mg/L
5  2004   238  Phosphorus-OrthoP 3.000e-03 1e-04  mg/L
5  2004   238      Phosphorus-TP 4.000e-03 1e-04  mg/L
5  2004   238        Nitrogen-TN 5.000e-02 1e-03  mg/L
5  2004   238       Nitrogen-NO3 1.000e-03 2e-03  mg/L
5  2004   238       Nitrogen-NO2 2.500e-03 5e-03  mg/L
5  2004   238 General-Alkalinity 6.500e+01 1e-02  mg/L
6  2004   237 General-Alkalinity 5.540e+01 1e-03  mg/L
6  2004   237  General-SolidsTSS 1.292e+01 1e-03  mg/L
6  2004   237       Nitrogen-NO2 2.000e-03 1e-03  mg/L
6  2004   237       Nitrogen-NO3 2.200e-02 1e-03  mg/L
6  2004   237       Nitrogen-TDN 9.000e-02 1e-03  mg/L
6  2004   237     Phosphorus-TDP 4.000e-03 1e-03  mg/L
7  2004   238 General-Alkalinity 4.430e+01 1e-03  mg/L
7  2004   238  General-SolidsTSS 2.340e+00 1e-03  mg/L
7  2004   238   Nitrogen-NO2+NO3 4.800e-02 1e-03  mg/L
7  2004   238       Nitrogen-TDN 2.700e-01 1e-03  mg/L
7  2004   238     Phosphorus-TDP 6.000e-03 1e-03  mg/L
8  2004   238       Nitrogen-NO3 1.000e-03 2e-03  mg/L
8  2004   238       Nitrogen-NO2 2.500e-03 5e-03  mg/L
9  2010   194                 Ca 1.450e+02 1e-01  mg/L
9  2010   194 General-Alkalinity 2.150e+02 5e-01  mg/L
9  2010   194   General-Hardness 4.800e+02 4e-01  mg/L
9  2010   194                SO4 2.540e+02 1e+01  mg/L
9  2010   194                 Bi 5.000e-07 1e-06  mg/L
9  2010   194                 Sn 2.500e-06 5e-06  mg/L
9  2010   194       Nitrogen-NO2 2.500e-03 5e-03  mg/L
9  2010   194       Nitrogen-NO3 2.500e-03 5e-03  mg/L
9  2010   194                 Br 1.000e-02 2e-02  mg/L
9  2010   194                  U 2.670e-03 5e-07  mg/L
9  2010   194                 Ag 3.000e-06 1e-06  mg/L
9  2010   194                 Be 1.300e-05 1e-06  mg/L
9  2010   194                 Cd 5.400e-05 1e-06  mg/L
9  2010   194                 Sb 8.500e-05 1e-06  mg/L
9  2010   194                 Tl 1.700e-05 1e-06  mg/L
9  2010   194                 Co 1.250e-03 2e-06  mg/L
9  2010   194                 Mo 1.510e-03 5e-06  mg/L
9  2010   194                 Pb 6.000e-05 5e-06  mg/L
9  2010   194                  V 3.860e-04 5e-06  mg/L
9  2010   194                 As 7.900e-04 1e-05  mg/L
9  2010   194                 Cr 1.600e-04 1e-05  mg/L
9  2010   194                 Li 3.230e-02 1e-05  mg/L", stringsAsFactors=F, header=T)
```

Cast it with data.table

```
library(data.table)
data$Variable <- gsub("\\+", "plus", data$Variable) #get rid of `+` for the sake of later pattern matching
setDT(data)
data2 <- dcast(data, Site+Year+Day~Variable, value.var = c("Value", "Error", "Unit"))
```

and reorder the columns

```
order_cols <- c()
for(i in unique(data$Variable)){
  order_cols <- append(order_cols, grep(paste0(i, "$"), names(data2)))
}
setcolorder(data2, c(1:3, order_cols))
```

In your original dataset (`data`) the column `Variable` has 29 unique values. For each level of `Variable`, 3 columns are generated (value, error and units) which gives 87 columns. 3 columns stay unchanged by the casting, namely (`Site`, `Year` and `Day`), which means all together you got the result `data2` with 90 columns. Finally, Each row represents each site.

Comment: Wonderful; this is exactly the result I wanted. Much appreciated and thanks for your time!